# can i shrink log file in full recovery model

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

i have configured Always on Availability group where iam unable to shrink log file size through simple recovery model. can i shrink the log file size in full recovery model if yes or possible then is there any impact for it..

Comment: You can shrink log file in any recovery model subject to condition that VLF are marked as free at the end of Log file. Please read [MSDN Document on Shrinking a log file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178037%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Shrinking of log file regularly is not advisable as it causes performance issues

Answer (score 2):

Shrinking a log file isn't generally a good idea unless you've had a large amount of unexpected log file growth - otherwise it'll only grow again, and a log file that grows can cause performance problems.

You can shrink a log file that's in any of the recovery models, but you won't always see the effect of it, as less of the file will be able to be shrunk - log records have to hang around until they have been backed up, transferred to other machines, and so on.

If you can put up with your log file being large, then that could be okay. Or try to shrink it to an okay size until it shrinks - maybe try every half hour until then? Once it can shrink, it will, and you can stop trying.